# Touch scren not responding

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Since yesterday, the touch screen of my ubuntu phone seems to be locked. The touch screen is not responding. I'm stuck on the SIM code screen because I can't type the code....

Physical buttons are ok, reboot is possible via long press of the on/off button, volume up and down ok also. I can boot on the boot menu (on and vol + buttons).

I had the problem before but a reboot solved the problem. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a "real" switch-off (e.g. for 20 seconds) also? It seems to me that sometimes there's a significant difference in behaviour between "reboot" and "switch off". For example, rebooting the phone from a normal state (without any problems) results in getting into a very long boot phase (flashing bq logo and so on for about 3 - 4 minutes). Switch-off, waiting for 20 seconds, switch-on results in a total boot time of approximately 20 seconds.

I researched this when i tried to find out if i was affected by this "bug": https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1439864

or if that was just "normal behaviour" .... (still i'm not sure:))